# How to run Excel macros from VS?

Tags: c#, excel

How to run Excel macros from VS2010(C#)?I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace

Answer (score 8):

Try this article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306683

The relevant part to run a macro is this (where `oApp` is the application instance in your code):

```
private void RunMacro(object oApp, object[] oRunArgs)
{
    oApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
        null, oApp, oRunArgs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to amarsuperstar's answer,

I'd like to state that you program needs to be a trusted source in order to call these macros. And the Excel-File itself needs to be trusted as well.